# IHTMLELEMENT get the text of onClick

Tags: mfc, webbrowser-control

I am requested to redirect an link in WebBrowser(MFC) ,

the link is sth like this :

```
"<a href="#" onclick="MyFunc" class="pinkbutton2" style="width: 230px;"><span>I am here</span></a>"
```

Currently , the IHtmlElement object of the Link is ready to me . Now How can I get the text of onClick. Thats saying "MyFunc".

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can access to the value behind the onclick attribute over **.getAttribute(name)**
Here is a reference http://www.mediaevent.de/javascript/DOM-Attribute.html

```
 var a = document.getElementById("test");
 alert(a.getAttribute("onclick");
```

Note that the a-Element must have an id attribute.

Comment: thanks 
But I used vc for the development.  
yes I really tried to get it by invoking get attribute.
The returned value is type of I dispatch . I don't know how to go further. Pls feel free to
enlighten me

Comment: I don't understand, please describe your problem with more information. Tpye of Idispatch? Javascript? Please post more Code.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion .
1 . Visual C++ is used for the development. As a result, the API might have some different in terms of the prototype.
2 . In VC , I also tried GetAttribute . The code is like this :
 _bstr_t bst_t("onclick");
 VARIANT vHref;    
 pElement->getAttribute(bst_t , 0 , &vHref ) ; 
        IDispatch *pDispatch  = vHref.pdispVal ; 
Then How can I get the "MyFunc" from the pDispatch ? 
Thanks